# Override a Standard Action with a Lightning Component not working for Contact New button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, quickaction, modal

I am trying to perform the Standard Action override with a lightning component as per the given trailhead

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/workshop-override-standard-action/steps/override_4

it is working correctly for custom object property.

However if i try to do it for standard object new button for contact, it is not working and the component opens on the contact tab instead and not as a modal popup.

Am I doing this wrong?